# How to remove entry from an object

Tags: javascript

How do I remove an entry, such as [2] from below?

```
var object = {};
object[0] = true;
object[1] = true;
object[2] = true;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
delete object["2"]
```

I would suggest you don't use "object" as your variable name. <del>"object" is a reserved word.</del>

Also, see this question: [how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

**EDIT:**

Actually "object" is not on [the list of reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). But "Object" (capital "O") [does have a meaning in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). So I would discourage using that name anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To remove object properties, use `delete`, like this:

```
delete object[2];
```